# Accessing browser cookies from .Net WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, cookies

I have an internal angular application which connects to a Web API for all business logic and data.  Company users can log in, and there is a cookie which stores an identifier.  The API is also aware of the identifier, and can associate it with the user/computer.   Now, I have some usb proxcard readers which have an SDK which can be used in .Net desktop applications for reading proxcards.  I want to have a .Net WinForms app running which reads the proxcard, and then can send the proxcard value to the API along with the identifier stored in the browser cookie (because the API needs to know the user/computer).  Is there a way I can read the browser cookies from my WinForms app in any of the top web browsers?  Or an alternative way I can get the identifier between the WinForms app and the browser app?  Thanks

Comment: You need winforms app to have its own authentication. Use the access token to further access the API. Let reading the cookies from winforms app can be a security flaw.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. When you signed up here you were encouraged to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please do so. It is expected that you have [fully researched this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) by the time you ask your question here and to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.